# Parse HTML string in Angular 2 and extract and update values

Tags: angular, svg

I just started working on an Angular project but am a bit stuck. I have a component that receives an HTML string from a (trusted) external source. I want to extract and update values from this string, and dispay it in my component.

Now displaying the string is easily done with the following code:

```
<div [innerHTML]="displayString"></div>
```

My input string has some `<span>` elements with the `data-card-text` element attached as identifier. Is it possible to extract this value, and update it whenever my component wants?

*Example:*
`let displayString:string = "<svg><text data-card-text>Value I want to update</text></svg>"`

Are operations like these even possible in Angular 2?

Comment: So what do you want to display? The text or render the whole string into HTML?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create one **Shared Service** in which all your **global variables** are defined like below. Your global variable is "**displayString**"

```
export interface SharedModel {
    displayString: string;
    dynamicValue: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class Shared {
    SharedComponent: SharedModel = {
           dynamicValue:'',
           displayString: '<svg><text data-card-text>'+this.SharedComponent.dynamicValue+'</text></svg>'
    };
}
```

Now access this service in your component where you need to set/get **displayString** as below.

```
import { Shared, SharedModel } from '../Shared';
export class MyComponent {
     public sharedData: SharedModel;
     constructor(public sharedResource: Shared)
     {
         this.sharedData = sharedResource.SharedComponent;
     }
}
```

**Assign Value:**(it may be in other component/service/APi in your case)

```
ngOnInit()
{
     this.sharedData.dynamicValue="My name is SANDIP PATEL"
}
```

**Access/Get** value in HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="sharedData.displayString"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use DomSanitizer from platform-browser module

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Inject DomSanitizer in your component by initializing it in your constructor

```
  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer)
```

use bypassSecurityTrustHtml()  of DomSanitizer  and pass your raw html content:

```
this.displayString= this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<svg><text data-card-text>Value I want to update</text></svg>");
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In you component you can just define variable `displayString` as a public and then you can use it in html

```
public displayString:string = "<svg><text data-card-text>Value I want to update</text></svg>";
```

Answer (score 2):

This operation doesn't require any angular functionality. One way to do it would be to construct a regular expression to match your string and retrieve the value.

However, you could also create an element using the external string and extract its innerText:

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
// when the string value changes
div.innerHTML = '<svg><text data-card-text>Value I want to update</text></svg>';
```

and in your component, set the displayString attribute to this value:

```
this.displayString = div.innerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to update the string value in the `<text data-card-text/>` element?

If so, you need to use regular expressions in order to extract the string inside the element. The output needs to be saved in a variable (i.e. `displayString`).

The variable can be added to the template in the following way:
`<div>{{displayString}}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar to display an html file constructed by an external application.

I use a wrapper component, passing in the html as an input parameter and implementing the **ngOnChanges** lifecycle hook to let Angular know there's a change to the html.

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'result-wrapper',
  template: `<div data-container></div>`
})
export class ResultWrapper implements OnChanges {

  @Input() displayString: string;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.setPageContent();
  }

  setPageContent() {
    const outerDiv = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('div[data-container]');
    outerDiv.innerHTML = this.displayString;
  }
}
```

Changes to the raw html are made in the parent component of ResultWrapper and passed in via attributes.
I use standard document methods as these seem most convenient. For example:

```
const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
tempDiv.innerHTML = displayString;
const dataCardText = tempDiv.querySelector('text[data-card-text]');
dataCardText.value = this.myValue;
return tempDiv.innerHTML;
```

A further note, if you want to style the displayString you should probably add style tags directly to it as Angular will have applied styles defined in @Component before your inner html is updated. Note that styles can 'bleed' into other parts of the page, so make sure they reference the `data-container` attribute in the wrapper template.

I'm assuming that the tags `<svg>` and `<text data-card-text>` may differ at runtime, if not you are obviously better off putting them in the template and interpolating the value. This would not need a wrapper component as `{{myValue}}` changes would be detected automatically.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  template: `<svg><text data-card-text>{{myValue}}</text></svg>`
})
```