# How to access the app.component variables and methods from other pages in Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to access and change `app.component.ts` variable or access methods from other pages (`otherpage.ts`) or other components such as;

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  accessedVariable: any;

  constructor(){ }

  accessedMethod() {
   ..something
  }

}
```

**otherpage.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-other',
  templateUrl: './otherpage.html',
})
export class OtherPage {

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Is `OtherPage` a child of `MyApp`?

Comment: @Dr.Geek can you explain briefly what you are trying to do especially that accessedMethod. Also, is app.component and otherpage parent related or completely separate from each other

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753236/4254681) would help. If you just want to change menu content in child page, just use [service](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2/angular2_services.htm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**18-02-2020**

Please don't use `Event emitter`. Use the `Observable` pattern. Otherwise, you'll have to face issues when updating to the [**Ionic 5**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/BREAKING.md#events-1). i.e. no Event API on `Ionic 5`.

**Original**

You can do this in a number of ways.

One method where I can tell you is using [**Events**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/).

> Events is a publish-subscribe style event system for sending and
>   responding to application-level events across your app.

Another method may be using the `provider`.On that use case, you can share your `methods` and `variables` through the `provider`.

Comment: It is not I want. I want to access app.component.ts means that there is something such as a variable I want to change from child page or otherpages. As an example `<ion-menu content>`, Is it possible to change ion content menu while change in child pages....

Comment: You can do it using `Events` as I mentioned in a `1st` method. Why can't you use that method? That is the only option you have according to your use case here.

Comment: Because if the project is first loaded, app.ccomponent (also menu-items ) loaded and after changes occur in the project pages we could not change the parameters in the existing app.component.ts ...

Comment: Hope you'll update your question with your specific use case.At this moment you just put a generic question. i.e. how to access method and variable.

Comment: I will try your answer first,  then I can change

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to use a **GlobalVars** Provider:

install it first with:

```
ionic g provider globalvars
```

this will automatically add the new provider to your **app.module.ts** file

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class GlobalVars { 
myGlobalVar: any;
constructor() { 
this.myGlobalVar = ""; 
} 

setMyGlobalVar(value) { 
this.myGlobalVar = value; 
}

getMyGlobalVar() { 
return this.myGlobalVar; 
} 
}
```

You define there **getter** and **setter** methods and the needed variable can be accessed through an Instance of this class! in **YourOtherPage.ts** you can get the variable with: **this.glVars.getMyGlobalVar()** for example.

here you can read more about it: https://ionicallyspeaking.com/2016/03/10/global-variables-in-ionic-2/

Comment: It is not that I want. I want to access app.component.ts !

Comment: I know I tried it too, but pages are capsuled in Ionic/Angular. You could try to trigger across your pages with jquery and your index.html as an alternative. I did that for my media database

Answer (score 0):

My use case Ionic 5 Capacitor: I wanted to show ion-spinner in ion-header of a header component. In the header component, I subscribe to the observable variable which I can set true in another service. The approach is flexible and I can use it in child or parent components/pages.

MyService.service.ts: (initialises the observable variable and set method)

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class MyService {

    spinnerBehavior = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    obSpinner: any = this.spinnerBehavior.asObservable();

    set spinner(showSpinner: boolean) {
        this.spinnerBehavior.next(showSpinner);
    }
}
```

AnotherService.service.ts:

```
export class AnotherService {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    public someMethod() {    
        this.myService.spinner = true;
    }
}
```

MyComponent.component.ts:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public showSpinner: boolean;

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.obSpinner.subscribe(showSpinner => {
          this.showSpinner = showSpinner;
        });
      }
}
```

MyComponent.component.html:

```
<ion-spinner *ngIf="showSpinner"></ion-spinner>
```